# Helper custom en Symfony

Tags: symfony3, servicio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Symfony 3 y me gustaría saber cual es la mejor manera de crear un Helper que pueda obtener unos parámetros definidos. Me explico:

Tengo un archivo de parámetros con unas keys de una Api definidas:

```
parameters:
    api.public.key: '123456789'
    api.private.key: 'ABCDEFGHI'
    api.timestamp: '1'
```

Ahora bien, quiero hacer un Helper definido aquí `Utils/ApiHelper.php` que pueda leer esos parámetros para mediante una función generar un hash.

He definido el helper como un servicio pero no se como enviarle los parámetros.

```
services:
    api.helper:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\ApiHelper
        public: true
```